# sql server migration assistant to mysql not connect to sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection

i want to migrate a mysql database to sql server. i have sql server 2008 and i have sql server migration assistant form mysql (SSMA) to do this.

when i connect SSMA to mysql connects well, but when i connect to SSMA to sql server tells me this:

```
Connection to SQL Server failed.
the connection to the server is set correctly, but there was an error in the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía.)
```

[image: this is the window to connect to sql server from SSMA]

the windows authentication not let me write the username and pass

but if i try to connect to sql server from the sql server 2008 management studio connects well.

[image]

why i can't to connect to sql server from SSMA??

thanks for responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that sql server not encrypt password, encripting password connects fine

Comment: May I know how to encrypting the password?